# R calculates quantile wrong or different?

Tags: r, quantile

I found an article that provides the algorithm for calculating quantile and R is apparently not following that article.

The article is:
https://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mb55/intro/quantile.htm

in R, I have the following code:

```
nv<-c(10,20,30,40)
quantile(nv)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
10.0 17.5 25.0 32.5 40.0
```

However, it seems that the quantile for 75% result is wrong
as according to the article, the formula is:

```
i = q(n+1)
```

and in my case(75%) q=0.75 and n=4 (4 observations in my combination)

```
X_j + (X_j+1 - X_j) times (i - j)
```

That means that it should be:

30 + (40-30)*(3.75-3) = **37.5** and not **32.5**

I am having a hard time thinking that R made a mistake.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the help page for `quantile`:

```
?quantile
```

you will see that quantiles can be calculated in different ways, which can be specified using the `type =` argument, with an integer from 1-9.

Type 6 gives the result that you were expecting:

```
quantile(c(10, 20, 30, 40), type = 6)

  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
10.0 12.5 25.0 37.5 40.0
```

Comment: You can also try `sapply(1:9, function(x) quantile(nv, probs = 0.75, type = x))` to see the answers given by all the different methods.

Comment: @neilfws, Thank you for the quick reply and Thank you, Marius, for the bonus multi-request format